# What does for loop mean?

Tags: java

I'm reading a java code, and it has a for loop as

```
for (PoolStaff staff : staffList)
```

I haven't seen this kind of fore loop written like this.  I'm used to seeing something like "for (int i = 0, i<5, i++" etc.

Can somebody just explain to me that for loop?

Comment: It is called a `foreach` loop or enhanced `for` loop. It is used to iterate a collection/array in readonly mode without needing to know its size.

Comment: To be fair, to the downvoters, it can be really hard to Google for things like this (which are really differentiated by special characters, which can't be Googled).  You kind of have to know it's called an "enhanced for loop" or not be a beginner. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is called an *enhanced for loop*, or a *for each loop*. It means for each item in the list, give it a temporary name and do something with it.

If the list is an array of primitives, like `int[]`, then the named variable is a copy. Any changes made to the copy will not be reflected in the original list. For example:

```
int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};
for(int i: myArray) {
   i = i + 1;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray)); // This prints 1, 2, 3!
```

If the list is an array of objects, like `staffList` in your question, then the named variable is a reference to the original object, and any changes to the named object will be reflected in the original list. For example:

```
Person[] myArray = {new Person("Alice", 23),
                    new Person("Bob", 20), 
                    new Person("Charlie", 25)};
for(Person person: myArray) {
   person.age = 30;
}
// Now every person in my list is 30 years old
```

You can get more information about for each loops from the official source, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Comment: I would rather say _reference it from a variable named `staff`_.

Comment: @Sotirios That is actually not true in all cases. If the for each loop is iterating over a primitive array, like int[], the new variable is not a reference but a copy. But I am not entirely correct either, so I'll update my answer.

Comment: @John Nice point about the primitive type array.  A lot of people (myself included) would've glossed over that detail.  Normally I wouldn't +1 an answer to this kind of question, but hell, I'm impressed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a ForEach loop. Basically it iteratea over all elements of the collection.